# amavisd-new rule to call external script

Tags: spamassassin

We are using **amavisd-new** (amavisd-new/oldstable,now 1:2.10.1-4) to filter both incomming and outgoing e-mails.

The thing is we receive a log of spam with fake sender from our domain. Since we have less than 100 accounts in our system, is there a plugin that can take the sender address then check it against a valid list of senders?
Thank you a lot.

our system configuration is:

- debian stretch
- amavisd-new/oldstable,now 1:2.10.1-4
- spamassassin/oldstable,oldstable,now 3.4.2-1

Answer (score 0):

If spamassassin checks outgoing email then perhaps a local rule that checks for allowed senders such as:

header LOCAL_WHITELIST From =~ /(me)|(you)|(etc)@mydomain.org/

meta LOCAL_WHITELIST_MATCH ((LOCAL_WHITELIST) =1)
score LOCAL_WHITELIST_MATCH -1.0

meta LOCAL_WHITELIST_MISS ((LOCAL_WHITELIST) =0)
score LOCAL_WHITELIST_MISS 1.0

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this just for outgoing email.

It should be straightforward to write a shell script that automatically generates the white list for you and creates the above as a whitelist.cf for spamassassin.  That would be cool. Especially if you could get it to run automatically after the creation or deletion of an email account and then amavisd-new reload && service amavisd-new restart.